# Setting up Dualshock 3 controller with retropie

Tags: retropie, gamepad

I installed retropie on my Rpi b+. everything good. setup Dualshock 3 drivers and paired with sixaxis utility.. the controller gets detected but the problem is , every time i start my Rpi the emulation station shows no gamepad detected even when my ps3 controller is connected and i have to reconfigure it every time...

so my question is ... it there anyway to permanently setup my ps3 controller so i don't have to reconfigure every time i start my retropie?

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow bluetooth to pair up with the controllers by adding extra 5 seconds during Emulation Station boot up. Please modify the following script:

At a command line, run the following:

```
cd /usr/bin/
sudo nano emulationstation
```

After the `#!/bin/bash` line, before the $es_bin, add the command `sleep 5` as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5

es_bin="/opt/retropie/supplementary/EmulationStation/emulationstation"
nb_lock_files=$(find /tmp -name ".X?-lock" | wc -l)
if [ $nb_lock_files -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "X is running. Please shut down X in order to mitigate problem with loosing keyboard input. For example, logout from LXDE"
    exit 1
fi

$es_bin "$@"
```

[RetroPie Project Official Blog](http://blog.petrockblock.com/forums/topic/controller-mapping-issue-es/#post-82880)